# model not changed with ng-show in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to toggle a div based on model value (true, false) and `ng-show`. Together with a `setTimeout` it does not work anymore. What is the reason?

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-show="abc">Div 1</div>
    <div ng-show="abc">Div 2</div>     
</div>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    setTimeout( function() {
        alert( "yeah" );
        $scope.abc = true;
    }, 1000 );
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aYt7K/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` doesnt trigger a digest cycle. You should be using Angular's `$timeout` service.

```
function Ctrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout( function() {
        alert( "yeah" );
        $scope.abc = true;
    }, 1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$timeout` instead, `setTimeout` doesn't force a digest since it isn't angular, so angular has no idea something has changed, `$timeout` calls a `$scope.$apply()` automatically, thus notifying watchers of changes.